# AWS Default Region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

When I see the `enum Regions`(amazonaws/regions/Regions.class) then I found the `DEFAULT_REGION = US_WEST_2`.

Where as, On URL https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-credentials.html I found that `If you don't select a region, then us-east-1 will be used by default.`

When I create AmazonS3 client using `new AmazonS3Client()`, it gives me `us-east-1` as default region.

So, my ask is:
1.) Are these default Regions are different for different services? For now, I'm just interested in AmazonS3Client/AmazonS3ClientBuilder.

2.) Is there any significance of these? Interested in `us-east-1` more..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default constructors have fixed endpoints, which (at least for the services I've used) are in `us-east-1`. You can change to a different region by calling the `setRegion()` or `setEndpoint()` method.

However, the default constructors have been deprecated since version 1.11.11. You should now use a client builder (such as [AmazonS3ClientBuilder](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3ClientBuilder.html)), which will look for a configured region. Unless you have a good reason to do otherwise, call `AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient()`.

Answer (score 3):

There is a great deal of significance in these.

For most services, the AWS regions are all independent.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html

Services in a given region are isolated from the same service in a different region, for operational resiliency.   If you create a bucket or an SQS queue or an SNS topic or a Lambda function in a far-away region, the laws of physics will impair your performance -- on a global scale, the speed of light becomes tediously slow to an extent that many people seem to underestimate.  If your bucket, queue, topic, etc., is in (e.g.) us-west-2, you cannot access it via the eu-west-2 endpoint.  You can access it from inside the eu-west-2 region, but your requests and their responses must traverse the ocean.

Use a region near your users and yourself.  Don't just take the defaults.  They are only there for historical reasons and hindsight suggests they were probably not a good idea. You may find that the default region is coincidentally your ideal choice of region, in which case use that region explicitly.

The us-east-1 region is the original, oldest, and largest region.  Customers who do not actively select a region have been subtly encouraged to use us-west-2 through some of the default settings for quite some time, presumably because there is more surplus capacity there, overall (but this is speculation). The us-east-1 default may still be present in some cases, but the trend seems to be toward removing defaults and requiring a selection, which is probably how it should always have been.